# How can I loop through an array of dates and group by week, month or custom quarter?

Tags: php, mysql, date, dateinterval

I am pulling out rows from a database based on date range and order by date, for example

```
SELECT date, code FROM records WHERE personid = '133'AND date >= '2017-02-10' AND date <= '2017-06-13' AND code IN ('P','T') ORDER BY date ASC
```

These records I like to group or order in particular ways.

One way has grouped the records by consecutive dates, for this, I have the following function:

```
 function getRecordsWithIntervals(array $records, $interval_size)
            {
                $intervals = array();
                foreach (array_chunk($records, $interval_size) as $interval_records) {
                    $first_record = reset($interval_records);
                    $interval = array(
                        'start' => $first_record['date'],
                        'codes' => array_column($interval_records, 'code'),
                        'count' => count($interval_records),

                    );
                    $intervals[] = $interval;
                }
                return $intervals;
            }
```

For a consecutive 5 days I call the function, like

```
getRecordsWithIntervals($records, 5);
```

But now I like to add the feature of the weekly, monthly or custom quarter. So for example:

```
getRecordsWithIntervals($records, 'weekly');
```

Would order/grouped $records per Mo-Sunday interval within the date range 2 Feb 2017 - 13 jun 2017???

This would be some sample data
[image]

I like to plot this Google chart
[image: Google Chart]

And this would be the generated JS with PHP for Feb and March

```
['Feb 6-12, 2017’,1,’1’],
['Feb 13-19, 2017’,4,’4’],
['Feb 20-26, 2017’,4,’4’],
['Feb 27-??, 2017’,5,’5’],
['Mar 6-12, 2017',5,'5'],
['Mar 13-19, 2017',5,'5'],
['Mar 20-26, 2017’,3,’3’],
['Mar 27-xx, 2017’,4,’4’],
```

Comment: may helps [Group by a range of X days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751018/group-by-a-range-of-x-days)

Comment: Please show us the exact output you want.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL might be a better place to conceptually form groups with your data.  For example, if you wanted to have the week number and month on tap you could just add these items to your select clause:

```
SELECT
    date,
    WEEK(date) AS week,
    MONTH(date) AS month,
    code
FROM records
WHERE
    personid = '133' AND
    date BETWEEN '2017-02-10' AND '2017-06-13' AND
    code IN ('P','T')
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: @tim-biegeliesen, Tx for the suggestion will add the query in my existing function. Might come back to you for a followup question, like I should group the outputs per week or month number, right? And how can this be done?

Comment: You should show us some expected output.  You are describing not one query, but several of them.

Comment: Yes you are correct I should show the expected output. but at them moment I am not sure. I want to ues it to plot a google chart. Your suggestion helps me  the right way, but what if i have 2016-02-11 - 2017-06-13 then the week and month numbers are not correct in order. just adding YEAR(date)?
I will add the expected output in my question later. Sorry for the inconvience